# ios display views and viewcontrollers on part of the screen

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitableview, instagram

I have this bug that I'm struggling with for a few days now. I basically want to make a profile much like Instagram has.

[image: Instagram user profile]

When you click on one of the first two buttons in the upper "tab bar" the content is displayed in the lower part. The upper part of the screen stays the same. I have some UIViewControllers and some UITableViewController. I have like 5 buttons that are suppose to display the viewcontrollers. My problem is that I can display a tableviewcontroller but if I try to display the second and then go back to the first, for instance, it gets stuck to the last one I displayed. I hope this is clear enough. here is the code for displaying the viewcontroller.

```
- (IBAction)wallButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    if(!_userWallViewController) {
        self.userWallViewController = [[WallViewController alloc] init];
        self.userWallViewController.activityFeedTableView.bounds = self.containerView.bounds;
    }

    [self.currentViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.currentViewController removeFromParentViewController];
    self.currentViewController = self.userWallViewController;
    self.userWallViewController.searchURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/event/user/%@", self.userID];
    self.userWallViewController.containerView = self.containerView;
    [self.containerView addSubview:self.userWallViewController.view];
    [self addChildViewController:self.userWallViewController];
    [self.userWallViewController.view setNeedsDisplay];
    [self.userWallViewController viewWillAppear:YES];
}
```

containerView is an UIView that takes the whole lower part of the screen. currentViewController is a placeholder viewController and userWallViewController is a UITableViewController.

Any kind of help is much appreciate. This is a real bugging situation. Thanks

Comment: Are any of those property setters overridden?  You should probably be explicitly setting the view's frame before it is added to the container.  self.currentViewController.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds;  Also some other tips: It shouldn't be necessary for the child vc to know about the container.  viewWillAppear, didAppear, willDisappear, didDisappear should either be handled properly if explicit, or implicitly handled (shouldn't really affect on your bug, but in general to make sure things work as expected). Add the child vc before adding the view. Don't need explicit display.

Comment: Hey. I wrote self.currentViewController.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds because when I was trying to display the tableviewcontrollers they would be rendered almost full screen. Also, the last two lines were added just to see if it fixes my bug in any way. Of course, it didn't. I also tried adding the child vc before adding the view. Did not work. Helping me with this won't go without tons of thank you and praise :)

Comment: You could try adding both views and child view controllers in viewDidLoad on the root controller, then for setting a selected view, just hide and unhide the right views.  You might also breakout the logic into another method so its easy to keep track; the button triggers [self showViewWithIndex:[buttonArray indexOfObject:button]].  After you get this working, you can try to optimize by removing views as needed, but this might be a simpler approach.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing a stupid mistake that was hard to identify bu @Matt's suggestion helped.

```
[self.fanOfViewController.containerView addSubview:self.fanOfViewController.userSimpleTableView];

[self.currentViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.currentViewController removeFromParentViewController];

self.fanOfViewController.containerView = self.containerView;
[self addChildViewController:self.fanOfViewController];
[self.containerView addSubview:self.fanOfViewController.view];

//CLEAN UP THE CONTAINER VIEW BY REMOVING THE PREVIOUS ADDED TABLE VIEWS
[self.userWallViewController.activityFeedTableView removeFromSuperview];
[self.userFansViewController.userSimpleTableView removeFromSuperview];
```

Each time I was adding a new tableView from it's view controller by pressing the corresponding button I was stacking it in the current's view container. When I was trying to remove the corresponding viewController from the hierarchy and then add it again the viewDidLoad method was not called (it was only called the first time). The was where I had my logic of removing the tableView.

Now I'm also adding it when the button is pressed and remove the other tableViews from the "stack". It may not be the very best way but I do plan to optimize it. I hope this is clear enough and helps anybody that comes across this problem.